# Why Does a Run In Borland TD yields a different result than a run without TD

Tags: assembly, tasm

I Have an odd problem in a program i wrote.
The task is to Use a Proc to locate Perfect numbers in the range of 1-2147483647.
When i run the program in TD for the number 28 it generates a correct answer, but when i run it without TD by simple execution, it tells the number is NOT perfect.

can someone help me understand what is the problem?

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA
Two DD 2
Num DD 0
Sum DD 0
Ten DD 10
PerfectRes DB ?

NotPerfect DB "The number is NOT Perfect$"
Perfect DB "The number is Perfect$"
InputNumMsg DB 'Enter number:',10,13,'$'
.CODE
.386

getPNum PROC NEAR       
 
 mov ah,1
 int 21h
 cmp al,13   ; Check if *Enter* was entered, If Yes - The user finished the input of A and the program continues to the input of B
 JE  endNumINPUT
 mov ah,0    ; Multi digital number    construction algorithm
 sub al,'0'  ; ASCII of 0 is decreased from the number to get the real value.
 add cx,ax                                  
 mov Num, ecx   ; The new number is put in A
 mov ax,cx
 mul Ten        ; number is multiplied by 10 because there is a potential for additional digit to be entered
 mov cx,ax
 jmp getPNum

 
 endNumINPUT:
 RET
 getPNum ENDP

 PNum PROC NEAR
 MOV EAX, NUM
 MOV EDX, 0
 DIV Two
 MOV ECX, EAX 

 numCHECK:
 MOV EAX, Num
 MOV EDX, 0
 DIV ECX
 CMP EDX, 0
 JE ToSum

 LOOP numCHECK

 ToSum:
 ADD Sum, ECX
 LOOP numCHECK     

 CheckSum:
 MOV EAX, Num
 CMP Sum, EAX
 JE isPerfect

 MOV PerfectRes , 0
 JMP PnumEnd

 isPerfect:
 MOV PerfectRes , 1 
 PnumEnd:    
 RET
 PNum ENDP  


Begin:
MOV AX,@DATA   ; Program prefix
MOV DS,AX      ; Set DS to point to data segment

MOV AH,9
MOV DX,Offset InputNumMsg
INT 21h

CALL getPNum
CALL PNum
CMP PerfectRes, 1
JE  PrintPerfect

MOV DX, OFFSET NotPerfect
JMP Print

PrintPerfect:
MOV DX, OFFSET Perfect

Print:
MOV AH, 9
INT 21h

MOV AH,4Ch     ; Set terminate option for int 21h
INT 21h        ; Return to DOS (terminate program)
END Begin
```

this is the run with TD:[image: Run With TD]

this is the run without TD:[image: Run Without TD]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are probably NOT initializing some register(s). TD always initialize registers. Try assigning zero to all the registers at startup. And don't forget the flags.

Comment: CX initialization was the problem, thanks!

Comment: You haven't indicated any troubleshooting, debugging or problem solving steps that you've taken.  Work out what you *think* should be happening and then step through your code in a  debugger to verify that it *is* happening.  When those two conditions are non-equal, you have found your misunderstanding or bug.

Comment: that's exactly it, when i ran the debugger, everything worked perfectly, but when i just ran the .exe file, it wasn't good. but after the suggestion of @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez, the program now runs without a problem.